# SyntaxError: Illegal return statement - searching for string in url

Tags: javascript, indexof

I'm just in the console in Chrome for now. I created this variable:

```
url = window.location.href
```

which gives:

url
"http://www.example.com/trips/dest/australia-and-south-pacific/cntry/fiji/"

Now I tried this:

```
if (url.indexOf('australia-and-south-pacific') > 0) {return 'foo';}
```

Which returned:

```
SyntaxError: Illegal return statement
```

I expected the console to return 'foo'.

Why is this happening? I noticed that after receiving this error, give it  afew seconds and a new error appears:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'hide' of undefined
```

If that helps to diagnose?

Comment: Because you are not in a function, so there is nothing to return to, maybe you wanted: `console.log('foo')`

Comment: You can't put a `return` statement anywhere but a function.

Comment: Ah OK, thank you I will update. Sorry this must have been super simple

Answer (score 8, accepted):

According to the [EMCAScript language specification](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-12.9),

> An ECMAScript program is considered syntactically incorrect if it
>   contains a return statement that is not within a FunctionBody.